# AngularJS data-ng-repeat with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm writing a thumbnail display using the Bootstrap css template.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href class="thumbnail"  data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.photosOfUser" ng-click="vm.doStuff($index)">
            <img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64, {{value}}" data-err-src="./images/icon.png"><!--alt="{{key}}"-->
        </a>
</div>
```

The images are being displayed perfectly. However, when I click each image link, nothing happens. I know it's kind of tricky dealing with ng-repeat with ng-click. I'm new to Angular so I was wondering if anyone could help :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The page is controlled as "vm" btw.

Comment: can you add the `vm.doStuff` method's code?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use ``vm.doStuff(key)`` or ``vm.doStuff(this)`` instead of ``$index`` here?

Comment: Sure. It's actually called initiateEditingSession. `function initiateEditingSession(idx){
            $("#open").css('display', 'none');
            vm.pId = Object.keys(vm.photosOfUser)[idx];
            vm.url = "http://localhost:8080/#/edit/" + pId;
            isInSession = true;
        }`

Comment: @Guido Kitzing Yes, you are probably right. See my function. That's not the question I'm asking though.

Comment: Is pId assigned a value? You set vm.pId instead I think

Comment: @jtsnr Wait what? I need $index to get the pId I need. Also, when I click the image link, nothing happens, meaning no console error or message at all. I don't think this is what causes the problem.

Comment: This bit of your function: vm.pId = Object.keys(vm.photosOfUser)[idx]; vm.url = "http://localhost:8080/#/edit/" + pId;   it looks like pId will be undefined so your call to the edit url will fail I expect